# exit(1) does not give me 1 as an exit value?

Tags: c, shell, exit, exit-code

Why when i execute this code inside a function in c

```c
int Pandoc(char *file)
{

    //printf("Pandoc is trying to convert the file...\n");

    // Forking
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1)
    {
        perror("Fork Error");
    }
    // child process because return value zero
    else if (pid == 0)
    {

        //printf("Hello from Child!\n");
        // Pandoc will run here.

        //calling pandoc
        // argv array for: ls -l
        // Just like in main, the argv array must be NULL terminated.
        // try to run ./a.out -x -y, it will work
        char *output = replaceWord(file, ".md", ".html");
        //checking if the file exists

        char *ls_args[] = {"pandoc", file, "-o", output, NULL};
        //                    ^
        //  use the name ls
        //  rather than the
        //  path to /bin/ls

        // Little explaination
        // The primary difference between execv and execvp is that with execv you have to provide the full path to the binary file (i.e., the program).
        // With execvp, you do not need to specify the full path because execvp will search the local environment variable PATH for the executable.
        if(file_exist(output)){execvp(ls_args[0], ls_args);}
        else
        {
            //Error Handeler
            fprintf(stdout, "pandoc should failed with exit 42\n");
            exit(42);
            printf( "hello\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get 0 as a returned value?

[image]

EDIT:
[image]
[image]

Edit:
So here i changed the return value of the main to 5.
The exit value for my function above to 42 (idk why tho)
It gives me 5 as an output.. no idea whats hapening.
I shouldve mentionned that i use fork() in my code.. Maybe its the reason.
[image]

I think that my exit shut off the child process but the main continiues.. so thats why its giving me the returned value inside of my main and not the exit one.

Comment: Does it work when you use another small value instead? Say, `exit(42)`?

Comment: What is the operating system?

Comment: That code you show should work. Either something else is going on (show the entire code), or your shell is not standard.

Comment: Hunch: replace `EXIT_FAILURE` with a hardcoded `1`. Also, add a print statement after the `exit` call. Just to prove exit didn't fail.

Comment: `EXIT_FAILURE` is actually the correct, portable, way. The value is implementation-defined. In this case `1` is probably expected, but it may compile to something else on another platform. (For example, on OpenVMS `1` would actually be success and not failure.)

Comment: Okay ill do that, also im connected via ssh to my school server to run some tests for my program.. so i have no control over that. (linux)

Comment: Also, try `./automd2h Readmfe.md; echo $?` in one line, to make sure its not due to a misconfigured shell somehow. But selbie is right, maybe the exiting itself is not working correctly - for example, you may have some [`atexit` handler](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Cleanups-on-Exit.html) that runs on exit and accidentally exits again but with success...

Comment: @CherryDT tried that, not working. i cant really show my whole program because its like 1k lines of code but i really dont know whats going on.. due to that all of my teacher tests are failing :/

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? Either it changes, or it does not. Either result may help us help you further diagnose the problem.

Comment: Also, try running `strace ./automd2h Readmfe.md 2> log.txt` please and put the resulting log.txt into a Pastebin or something and link it here. Especially the last few lines would be interesting.

Comment: And, to rule out a shell issue: What do you get when running `false` (which is a tool whose sole job is to exit with code 1) followed by `echo $?`?

Comment: @Hazel if the problem doesn't occur with `int main(void) { return 42; }` but does occur in the real code, then you should be able to divide and conquer until you find out what is going on

Comment: I tried an exit (42) and it still print me 0 for my echo. @usr2564301

Comment: updated my post

Comment: To rule out specific `exit` misbehaviour, can you also try `return 42`? Just to iterate through all possible permutations – theoretically it should work exactly the same.

Comment: `fork` was the missing puzzle piece... So you are exiting from another process, not the one that the shell was waiting for! That explains it all.

Comment: @CherryDT haha yeaa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your child process exits with an exotic value, but your main process always exits with 0, and that's what determines `$?`.

If you want `$?` to be the exit value of the child process, you'll have to `wait()` for it, retrieve the child's exit code, and then exit your main process with it.